# How to manage rails asset does not have gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, assets

We always have ruby gem of famous javascript or css lib such as bootstrap-sass, ember-rails. But for some js lib such as bootstrap-lightbox, there are no gems sometimes. In order to manage these asset automatically, I found the jail(https://github.com/charly/jail) gem. But it seems that project is not so active now. Are there any better solution then just download and past file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many of those "assets gems" are just a basic skeleton with js/css assets, it should not be too hard to build your own and publish on rubygems!

An advantage of this, beside locking versions in `Gemfile`, is that you have control over them and don't risk screwing everything up during a `bundle update`.

I have found issues using external gems for managing assets, especially with bootstrap ones, sometimes the precompilation will break or they will upgrade the assets inside, breaking the entire site (or minuscole portions that you may hardly notice) with not-so-wanted changes.